# How to implement a UI effect like the google plus for android?

Tags: android, android-layout, google-plus

I meet a difficult problem. I want to implement the UI effect like Google plus. I try hard. I use `CoordinatorLayout`, `NestedScrollView`, `ViewPager` and fragments as viewpager's content, but I failed.

If everyone know how to do, please help me. I'm so tired as this.

Comment: post your code then

Answer (score 0):

I had also faced same problem as you and i had found one solution for better look same as google+ app , For implementing that type of app you must use these api mikepenz/MaterialDrawer . It have very good navigation drawer with wonderful look and feel it is available here [mikepenz](https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer)

Comment: Thank you .It's a cool thing,but I feel difficult is the bottom bar and toolbar in google plus.I can implement the toolbar effect ,i also know it should use Behavior,but i can not understand how to click a item in the bottombar,then change.And also if horizontal scroll then change the content.